# Passing cell label or title to another view controller

Tags: ios

I have tableview controller with 5 rows/cells. I simply assign these cells text/title by using a NSArray.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
  *)indexPath       
  {
  static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
  }
```

Now I want that when I select a particular cell, the particular cell title/text is passed to another another view controller. So that I can use that text like this

```
 if(cell.text=="this"){
  ...do this
  }
```

Can anybody help me or give me better solution?

Comment: Do you mean with 'select' to start a segue based on a tableRow click?

Comment: yes, it can be seque based.

Answer (score 0):

Well you want to do this in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. So when they select a row, you push the next view controller and you initialize that viewController with cell.label.text as the title. Basically it will look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NewViewController *newView = [[NewViewController alloc] init];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
UILabel * myLabel = (UILabel *) [newView.view viewWithTag:1];
myLabel.text = [title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

That's assuming you want a label in the new view to equal the text of the cell you click on. You would have to set this label's tag to be 1 within the interface builder.

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is used in tableViewClass, but I want to access the cell text in another view controller

Comment: well you are starting from a tableView, so you have to make that tableView push the information to the next viewcontroller. See my edits

Comment: I still do not understand. Here we are initializing NewViewController. What is title? How can we use this information in NewViewController

Comment: I tried, error, use of undeclared identifier 'title'

Comment: you're essentially setting it how you set your cell label. Don't you use an array called title in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Apple has explained in there [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH5-SW11) how to move data from one view controller to another.

Im short you implement the:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Have a look at above link and section 3-1 "Passing data to a destination view controller".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Make a NSString property in a SecondViewController. It should be like this:
`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lblText;`
(Give whatever name you like to the variable).

I am assuming that you are using storyboard. If not, then please make navigation as we do with XIB files.

Now, Come to the first view controller.

Make a property of UILable to set the text on row of tableview. It'll be also use to pass the value to the next viewcontroller.

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *lbl;

In first view controller's implementation file write the following code in this delegate method of UITableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
  *)indexPath 
 {
    lbl = [cell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Now, use delegate method of UITableview -didSelectRowAtIndexpath. and write following code inside it.

```
{
    SecondViewController *vc = (SecondViewController *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewController:@"SecondViewController"];
    vc.lblText = lbl.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Now. you have your label value in variable lblText, so you can use this anywhere in your Second View (i.e. New View).

Comment: I did this but vc.IblText is not working. It is not calling the SecondViewController lbl.Text.

Answer (score 0):

in the other viewController you have to add a property

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;
```

in your tableViewController with the 5 cells you implement this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" sender:tableView];
}
```

and this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Identifier"]) {

      UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)sender;

    // here is the other ViewController init
      ViewController *vc =(ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

      vc.text = [self.title objectAtIndex:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];      
  }

}
```

in the other ViewController you can do something like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   if ([text isEqualsToString:@"game"]){

    Nslog(@"New Game");

   }

}
```

hope it work for you

Comment: Same problem, I do not know why vc.text is not visible in my TableViewController. Is this something to do with delegation or datasource.

Comment: vc.text is a property from the other ViewController, you have to instanciate the viewController and then use it.did you added the code that I suggested you??

Comment: what you need is to pass data from a tableViewController to a ViewController depending on which cell of the table was selected?

Comment: Depending on which cell selected, I want to pass the cell lable/text to another view controller class. I need to use that text for identification purpose.

Comment: i tried what you want and with this code i'm able to pass the text in the cell to another viewController ... i just to add the performo Segue just like i told you to do and in the prepare Segue you access the property of the nextViewController, i really don't understand why i did not work... i just made a new proyect with two ViewControllers and everything works perfectly, if you want i can upload it at github and you can access the source code to see what are you doing wrong